# systemLayoutSizeFitting not returning proper size of view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I'm setting a view controller's view as my UITableView's header.

```
var headerView = CommunityPostDetailTableHeaderViewController()

override func viewDidLoad() {

   // other stuffs

   headerView.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.tableView.frame.size.width, height: 100)
   headerView.delegate = self
   self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView.view
}
```

And using this bit of code to resize it according to the size of view.

```
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        
        if let headerView = tableView.tableHeaderView {
            
            let height = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(CGSize(width: tableView.bounds.width, height: 0)).height
            var headerFrame = headerView.frame
            
            // Comparison necessary to avoid infinite loop
            if height != headerFrame.size.height {
                headerFrame.size.height = height
                headerView.frame = headerFrame
                tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm using this technique for two of my table views.

1. tableview is presented directly from a view controller like so :

```
let playerController = VideoDetailController()
playerController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
playerController.video = video
self.present(playerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Working fine in all iOS devices.

2. the other is presented by embedding inside a navigation controller :

```
let communityPostDetailVC = CommunityPostDetailViewController()
communityPostDetailVC.delegate = self
if let indexpath = indexpath {
   communityPostDetailVC.communityPost = datasource[indexpath.row]
   communityPostDetailVC.indexpath = indexpath
}
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: communityPostDetailVC)
navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
self.present(navigationController, animated: true)
```

Not resizing properly on iPhone 5/5s/SE(1st gen)/6/6s/7/8/SE(2nd gen).
I can't figure out why it is not working on smaller phones. You can see blank space in the comparison attachment below. In smaller SE the space is even more.

Any suggestions/ideas are welcome. I'm clueless at this point.

PS: I've nested view controller's. the headerView is a view controller holding another view controller's view. The FB logo and the pink label underneath is part of the nested view controller. Other than that everything else is in headerView's view controller's view.

[image: Visual Representation]

Answer (score -1):

you are using fullscreen , but you image is a fixed size image . pink colour view also fixed size.
maybe its making a problem .

its actually not an answer. a suggestion for you. you may review again your code. hope you will find .

happy coding

Comment: If it's not an answer, please don't put it in the Answer field.

Comment: I tried to help him. no one was answered , then I got -1 
ha ha. nice